# .htaccess redirect from old to new

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

I have need to redirect (301) old url to new url. Here "XYZ" is a dynamic string variable. How can do this in apache2 ?.please help

old url is https://example.net/abc/XYZ/page?ref=XYZ-content and 
new url is https://example.net/abc/XYZ/page/content

Comment: Is this Apache2 or Nginx?

Comment: There are about 558275932 examples currently for exactly what you ask here on SO. None of all those answers solves your question? _Why not?_ And why should the 558275933rd answer make a difference? Or take a look of the documentation of the rewriting module or feature of your http server, they come with good examples too.

Comment: Arkascha is right, this is a quick google: `Redirect 301 /abc/(.+)/page?ref=(.+)-content https://example.net/abc/$1/page/content` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#movehomedirs

Comment: @varlogtim Redirect directive does not support a regex based pattern. Did you mean **RedirectMatch**

Comment: Yes, derp! Haha, I linked the correct docs...